# No Polish diacretic letters in JSON output. How to get them?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, character-encoding, system.text.json

When I try to write serialized object to a file, I end up with JSON file without any diacretic characters (Polish in this case). Did I miss something obvious here, or I omitted a lot of things to set things up in proper way?

I'm `using System.Text.Json`

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
           
var stringoo = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(paginatedData);

using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(stream)
{
    writetext.Write(stringoo);
}
```

The object `paginatedData` is a result table from Db query, organized and displayed in custom view model. It is being displayed properly in VS, in .html views and it's successfully exported to .xlsx file, all without any encoding issues.

The object `stringoo` is properly displayed in VS in JSON visualizer (when hitting breakpoint).

I tried: `using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode)`  without success.

I will appreciate any help or direction for further research.

Answer (score 1):

By default, JSON serializer only retain printable characters in ASCII, other characters will be escaped as `\uXXXX`, you need to specify a non default encoder to retain particular characters.

```
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text.Unicode;

var encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin,
                                       UnicodeRanges.LatinExtendedA);
var option = new JsonSerializerOptions { Encoder = encoder };
var stringoo = JsonSerializer.Serialize(paginatedData, option);
```

Also note that there are two types of diacritic characters in Unicode, one is a single character and another is an ASCII letter combined with a diacritical mark. For instance `ę` (`\u0119`) and `ę` (`e\u0328`) look the same, the former belongs to *Latin Extended-A*, the later belongs to *Combining Diacritical Marks*, the above code only prevents the former from being escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the encoding explicitly when creating your StreamWriter:
Use `Encoding.UTF8` instead of `Encoding.Unicode`

```
using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writetext.Write(stringoo);
}
```